# Lightweight Reflection in C++

Tags: c++, boost, reflection

I have a distributed c++ application and one machine wants the other machine to invoke a specific function on a specific object. The sender knows the type of the object and the pointer of it on the receiver. I can send a member function pointer to the receiver but I'm not sure how to send the type to enable a cast of the this pointer to the appropriate type.

Ideally the mapping could be done statically (is there a way using boost::mpl and boost::variant)? I know the set of types that could be invoked at compile time (both machines run the exact same binary as well). Also the signature of the function is fixed (let's say it returns void and takes an int always, regardless of type).

Comment: It's more like RPC than reflection...

Comment: looks like you want to make a RPC call, not reflection

Comment: Maybe [google protobuf's Service feature](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#services) is helpful for implementing this.

Comment: "I can send a member function pointer to the receiver" how do you go about doing that? This sounds extremely suspicious - much harder than communicating a type between the client and the server.

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments, you can use RPC ([remote procedure call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call)) for that.

The idea is to define a protocol for which both sides agree how a call, parameters and return values are represented over the network.

Depending on your environment, you can choose an existing RPC library (see a list in the wiki article linked), or write something simple on your own while using existing serialization and communication modules (see for example google protobufs, or boost asio).

Answer (score -1):

COM remote activation seems to be pretty good for that. The only possible issue is security restrictions on a given network.

Comment: COM is pretty restricted technology for Windows based platforms, isn't it?

Comment: @g-makulik: if he's planning to work only on Windows that's a possible choice, it has the advantage of being ready made, widely used and has binding for many languages.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Wizards, fairies, visionaries and 'good guessers': All the same!

Comment: @g-makulik: well, COM *does* involve a lot of black magic... :)

Comment: @MatteoItalia COM is a pretty messed up crap IMHO! Had to work with it some times, never liked it, it's hell of error prone and being a installation and configuration mess. That's not what I'd call black magic, but just bungling!

Comment: @g-makulik: I know, I too had to work a bit with COM, the less I see it the more I'm happy. What I'm saying is just that sometimes it can be a possible solution for the reasons said above.